# Intersection of two subspaces is trivial or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb {F}.$ Let $S=\{\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_s\}$ be any linearly independent set and also $\{\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_r\}\subset V$ such that $S\cup \{\beta_i\} $ are distinct $s+1$ dimensional subspaces of $V.$ Further assume that $s+r < \dim(V).$ Now the question is: can I say $\langle \beta_1,\ldots,\beta_r\rangle \cap \langle S\rangle=\{0\}$ ?

I am not sure if it is true or not. Help me to prove it if it is true. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not true in general. Counter-Example: $s=1$, $r=3$,

$$\alpha_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}, \beta_1=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\beta_2=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\beta_3=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $\langle\alpha_1,\beta_1\rangle$, $\langle\alpha_1,\beta_2\rangle$, $\langle\alpha_1,\beta_3\rangle$ are distinct $2$-dimensional spaces, but $\langle\alpha_1\rangle\cap\langle\beta_1,\beta_2,\beta_3\rangle=\langle\alpha_1\rangle\neq\{0\}$.